# Punctuation when 'another' refers to a modified noun

Tags: punctuation

I'm helping edit a piece of fiction, which has a sentence that begins so:

> In another smaller kitchen...

How is this to be punctuated?
One choice is to leave it as it is. Another is using two commas:

> "In another, smaller, kitchen..."

Since 'another' isn't an adjective or adverb, the usual rule(s) about grouped modifiers don't apply.

(Note that there is a different kitchen several paragraphs before the line in question.)

So--commas, no commas? (I can't see 'one comma' being right)

Comment: Commas are audible. How do you want it to sound in your readers' ears?

Answer (score 4):

The form without commas isn't *incorrect*, but it implies there are at least three kitchens in the narrative:

> In the main kitchen, X happened; in one of the smaller kitchens, Y happened; and, in **another smaller kitchen**, Z happened.

If, as I assume, there are only two kitchens in the narrative, both commas are needed.

> In one kitchen, X happened; in **another, smaller, kitchen**, Y happened.

Comment: +1: You’re right that bracketing commas are needed to indicate that the attribute immediately following *another* is to apply **restrictively** to the head noun following rather than **descriptively** to both the former noun and the latter one alike.

Comment: Yes. << another smaller kitchen >> = << another [smaller kitchen] >> while << another, smaller, kitchen >> = << another kitchen, this one smaller >>.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few rules that I've seen when it comes to commas in multiple adjectives:

- If you can swap the order of the adjectives, add a comma ("fat, wet dog" "wet, fat dog")
- If you can add "and" between the adjectives to achieve the same meaning ("wet and fat dog" to "wet, fat dog")
- If none of the adjectives is part of the noun phrase ("tangled gray beard" gets no comma because "tangled" describes a "gray beard")

Your phrase "another small kitchen" meets none of these.

"Small, another kitchen" doesn't make sense.

"Another and small kitchen" doesn't make sense.

"Another" applies to the "small kitchen" and implies that the author has already mentioned a small kitchen.